# Skills as a Victory Tie-Breaker

Tags: tales-of-arabian-nights

**How are skills counted for the victory condition?**

The first tie-breaker for winning the game is the number of statuses each contested player possesses, followed second by how many skills they possess.  When counting skills for this reason, are skill tiles counted as 1 skill regardless of level (Talent vs. Mastery), or do Mastery skills count as 2 skills each (similarly to how they are most commonly gained by receiving a skill twice)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Master level skills still count as one.** [The rules](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/tales_of_the_arabian_nights_rules.pdf) don't cover this directly. However, page 13 says:

> Certain paragraphs will instruct you to lose a particular skill. If you have that skill at the Talent level, put it back in the Skill Bank. If you have the skill at Master level, turn it back to its Talent side.

It seems fairly clear that a Master level skill still only counts as one skill. The rules have special cases throughout for how you handle gaining and losing skills at different levels, with the result being that you can only ever have one skill token for a particular skill you have.

In other words, for each skill, **you either have it or you don't**. This is true regardless of whether you have the skill at Master or Talent level.

As extra evidence, the game is designed so that you have only one skill token and flip it. If being a Master was equivalent to having the skill twice, you'd represent it by having the token twice instead of the token having two sides. As such, the game designer didn't consider this interpretation and so the rules don't cover it.